# I would like to do the same in views that admin.register decorator does in admin

Tags: django, django-views

I would like to be able to register different models from a single front view, as I can do from the admin create view.

for example in models.py:

```
class Book(models.Model):
   """Model representing a book (but not a specific copy of a book)."""
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
    null=True)
```

in admin.py I have:

```
@admin.register(Author)
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
```

[in the admin panel I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuMoQ.png)

I would like to be able to add author by the same way from the create book view in frontend, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

> For this make create modelform for Book Model in `forms.py`

```
class AddBook(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
           model = Book
           fields = ['title','author']
```

> set url for adding the book in `urls.py`

```
path('add/book/',views.add_book,name='add_book')
```

> In views.py

```
def add_book(request):
if request.method == POST:
    form = AddBook(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
    book = form.save(commit=False)
    book.save()
    return redirect('redirect where you want to redirect')
else:
    form = AddBook()
return render (request,'add_book.html',{'form':form})
```

> add_book.html

```
<form action= '{% url 'add_book' %} method='post'>
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type = 'submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

> *OR you can you use the built-in class-based generic views* https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/